# A dictionary controls a turtle's movement

Tags: python, string, function, dictionary, turtle-graphics

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to solve a task that I got from school. I have to build a function that uses a turtle to draw something, from an argument of type string (such as 'fdltfd' - move forward, left and forward again). These commands are in a dictionary, so I have to compare the elements from the string with the dictionary keys. If they match, command the turtle to move. The code that I wrote:

```
def execute(turtle, length, args, *cmd):

map = {'fd': turtle.fd(length), 'lt': turtle.lt(args), 'bk': turtle.bk(length), 'rt': turtle.rt(args), 'nop':None}

for command in cmd:
  if command in map.keys():
      map[command]()

execute(bob, 50, 45, 'fdltfd' )
```

The problem is that the turtle does just what's in the dictionary, moves forward, backward, left and right, it does not even bother looking at my `for` loop.

Can you please give me some ideas of how I could make this work? Or if I am thinking about it right? Of course, not the code for that :)...Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific problems with your code:  The asterisk in front of the `cmd` argument is incorrect:

```
def execute(turtle, length, args, *cmd):
```

given the way you're invoking it:

```
execute(bob, 50, 45, 'fdltfd')
```

So get rid of the asterisk.  The parameter `turtle` is also the name of a package so change it, e.g. `my_turtle`.  Similarly `map` is the name of a Python built-in, so change it.

Your dictionary should contain functions to call, not the results of calling functions. I.e. instead of:

```
map = {'fd': turtle.fd(length), 'lt': turtle.lt(args), 'bk': turtle.bk(length), 'rt': turtle.rt(args), 'nop':None}
```

I'd expect something more like:

```
commands = {'fd': turtle.fd, 'lt': turtle.lt, 'bk': turtle.bk, 'rt': turtle.rt, 'nop': None}
```

or:

```
LENGTH = 50
ANGLE = 45

commands = { \
    'fd': lambda t: t.fd(LENGTH), \
    'lt': lambda t: t.lt(ANGLE), \
    'bk': lambda t: t.bk(LENGTH), \
    'rt': lambda t: t.rt(ANGLE), \
    }
```

Given the value of `cmd`, `'fdltfd'`, I don't see how you expect this to work:

```
for command in cmd:
```

as it would lookup 'f', 'd', 'l', 't', etc. in the dictionary instead of 'fd', 'lt', etc.  You probably want something more like:

```
# 'fdltfd' -> ['fd', 'lt', 'fd']
for command in [a + b for a, b in zip(cmd[0::2], cmd[1::2])]:
```

Putting all the above together, we get a rough implementation that basically works:

```
import turtle

LENGTH = 50
ANGLE = 45

commands = { \
    'fd': lambda t: t.fd(LENGTH), \
    'lt': lambda t: t.lt(ANGLE), \
    'bk': lambda t: t.bk(LENGTH), \
    'rt': lambda t: t.rt(ANGLE), \
    }

def execute(my_turtle, cmd):
    for command in [a + b for a, b in zip(cmd[0::2], cmd[1::2])]:
        if command in commands:
            commands[command](my_turtle)

execute(turtle.Turtle(), 'fdltfdltfdltfdltfdltfdltfdltfd')

turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. You are a lifesaver. With your help, I managed changing the execute function, so now it also takes LENGTH and ANGLE as arguments. I also forgot about lambda. So, my turtle is based entirely on the function. Again, thank you very much.